# jQuery Image slider not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have designed an image slider that slides through the pictures . But I want it also to display that specific image associated to that corresponding button user clicks on i.e. if user clicks 3rd button it would display the 3rd image and then it should slide on normally.
I have coded that but it is not working as expected in fact it is not working at all . can anyone point me out where am I doing wrong ?
and help me solve that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>jQuery UI Dialog: Hide the Close Button/Title Bar</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    .mySlider
    {
        width:800px;
        height:480px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:40px auto;
        background-image:url(Images/Loading.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        background-color:#fff;
    }

    .shadow_div
    {
        background-image:url(Images/shadow.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:top;
        width:800px;
        height:30px;
        margin:-39px auto;

    }

    .mySlider img
    {
        width:800px;
        height:480px;
        display:none;

    }

    .Parent_Slider > a
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:bold;
        width:32px;
        height:32px;
        position:absolute;
        top:45%;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        display:block;
         border:1px solid white;
    }

    .Next_Class
    {
        right: 282px;
        background-image: url(Images/rightarrow.jpg);
    }

    .Prev_Class
    {
        left:282px;
        background-image:url(Images/leftarrow.jpg);
    }

    ul.Round_Buttons
    {
        position:relative;
        left:35%;
        top:5px;
        text-decoration:none;
        list-style-type:none;
        text-indent:-9999px
    }

   ul.Round_Buttons li
   {
       float:left;
       background-color:white;
       margin:1px 5px;
       padding:0px 7px;
       border-radius:50%;
       border-width:1px;
       border:1px solid #3610a5;
       cursor:pointer;
       box-shadow:1px -1px 3px 1px #3610a5;
       transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
       -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;

   }


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var count = 1;
    var temp_count = 0;
    var _tempClicked = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(("#my_image_slider>#")+count).show("fade", 1000);
        $(("#my_image_slider>#")+count).delay(3500).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 800);

        var image_count = $("#my_image_slider > img").length;//total number of images

        $(".Round_Buttons li").click(function () {
            temp_count = this.id.charAt(0);
            _tempClicked = true;
        });

        count = count + 1;

        setInterval(function () {
            alert("In setinterval --- " + count);
            $(("#my_image_slider #") + count).show("slide", { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
            $(("#my_image_slider #") + count).delay(3500).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 800);

            if (count == image_count) {
                count = 1;
                alert("In first If -- " + count);

            }
            else if (_tempClicked == true) {
                count = temp_count;
                alert("In Else If " + count);
            }
            else {
                count = count + 1;
                alert("In else -- " + count);
            }
        }, 5300);

    });



</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Parent_Slider">
    <div id="my_image_slider" class="mySlider">
        <img id="1" src="Images/bmw.jpg" alt="" title="Audi India"/>
        <img id="2" src="Images/audi.jpg" alt="" title="BMW India" />
        <img id="3" src="Images/aston-martin.jpg" alt="" title="Aston-Martin APAC" />
        <img id="4" src="Images/bugatti.jpg" alt="" title="Buggatti APAC" />
        <img id="5" src="Images/koenigsegg.jpg" alt="" title="Koenigsegg APAC" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="Next_Class">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="Prev_Class">Prev</a>
</div>
    <div class="shadow_div" >
        <ul class="Round_Buttons">
            <li id="1_Round_Buttons"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="2_Round_Buttons"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="3_Round_Buttons"><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li id="4_Round_Buttons"><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li id="5_Round_Buttons"><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click function it is setting a value that is picked up later by setInterval, so it may appear to not work immediately.  Also _tempClicked is not reset to false after it's checked in setInterval so you would never see the user's clicks after the first one.

For immediate UI response you can try something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var count = 1;
    var _tempClicked = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var image_count = $("#my_image_slider > img").length;//total number of images

        increment_counter = function(){
            if (count == image_count) {
                count = 1;
            }
            else {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        };

        doslide = function(){
            $("#my_image_slider>#"+count).show("fade", 1000);
            $("#my_image_slider>#"+count).delay(3500).hide("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 800);
            increment_counter();
        };

        doslide();

        setInterval(function () {
            doslide();          
        }, 5300);


        $(".Round_Buttons li").click(function () {
            count = parseFloat(this.id.charAt(0));
            // hide currently visible image
            $('#my_image_slider').children().each(function(index,obj) {
                if( $(obj).css("visibility") != "hidden"){
                    $(obj).hide();  
                };
            });
            $("#my_image_slider>#"+count).show();
        });


    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have error in your code:

```
$(("#my_image_slider>#")+count)
```

this type of selector is wrong, instead use this type of selector

(you should remove inner parentheses):

```
$("#my_image_slider>#" + count )
```

**NOTE**:  jQuery selector should be a string.